# How to get parent attributes from a child method attribute in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have this code:

```
def some_method():
    #i need to get some attrs :(
    return 'blabla'

setattr(parent, 'new_attr', some_method)
```

it's there a way to get other attributes of the parent inside the `some_method` function?

Thanks in advance!

**Update: (solution)**

I solved in this way, i don't know if the best.

```
def some_method(parent):
    # print or do something parent.xy_attribute
    return 'blabla'

parent.new_attr = some_method(parent)
```

and it works!

Thanks again!

Comment: any object that have other attributes

Comment: You need to post more information about what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `parent` were a class, then you can access its attributes like you would with any other method of a class, by giving the self parameter and using that.

If it isn't a class, perhaps the best way to handle this would be to write your function within a wrapper/factory/something instead of as a method directly.

```
def some_method_wrapper(parent):

    def some_method():
        #access any parent attribute 
        #by using the parent positional argument passed to the function
        print parent.desired_attribute
        return 'blabla'

    setattr(parent, 'new_attr', some_method)
```

You can then use `parent.new_attr()` and it'll be able to print/manipulate/whatever any parent attributes you want.

Here's a more fleshed out example of how you might use this to manipulate a counter on a function (or, say, flush a function cache).

```
def parent_function(numbers):
    # do something with numbers
    parent_function.counter += 1
    return sum(numbers)

parent_function.counter = 0

def add_reset_function(parent):

    def reset_counter():
        parent.counter = 0

    setattr(parent, 'reset', reset_counter)

# call parent_function a few times

numbers = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(4): parent_function(numbers)
print parent_function.counter # 4

add_reset_function(parent_function)

# call the reset function just added
parent_function.reset()

print parent_function.counter # 0
parent_function(numbers)
print parent_function.counter # 1
```

Comment: this snippet was helpful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is to create a [`MethodType`](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.MethodType) object to assign (from [`types`](http://docs.python.org/library/types.html)).

```
import types

setattr(parent, 'new_attr', types.MethodType(some_method, parent, type(parent)))
```

Comment: and how can i get attrs in parent?

Comment: You'd have `some_method` take a `self` parameter, just like any other normal method.